# Add "data-" attribute to image links

Tags: images, hooks, lightbox

Is it possible to add an attribute and value to image links?

I currently have:

```
<a href="#">
  <img class="img-responsive aligncenter wp-image-1286 size-full" src="#" alt="..." width="858" height="304">
</a>
```

and would like to add `data-rel="lightbox-0"` to the link:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="lightbox-0">
  <img class="img-responsive aligncenter wp-image-1286 size-full" src="#" alt="..." width="858" height="304">
</a>
```

I also need to add the new attribute to images in a specific taxonomy but I think I can figure out that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while googling about the same issue I came upon your question and a similar question from the Wordpress forums. You can control the output of the generated code via the image_send_to_editor filter like this:

```
function filter_image_send_to_editor($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
  $html = sprintf('<a href="#" data-rel="lightbox-0"><img alt="%2$s" src="%1$s" /></a>', esc_attr(esc_url($url)), esc_attr($title));

  return $html;
}

add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'filter_image_send_to_editor', 10, 8);
```

Original link: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-generated-html-code-from-add-media-button